# How to update training dataset at epoch begin in Huggingface Trainer using Callback?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

I want to recreate the training dataset by a function `generate_custom_train_set` at the beginning of every epoch, however, is there a way I could do it with Trainer using callback?

My trainer looks like

```
trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=args,
        train_dataset=train_dataset.,
        eval_dataset=validation_dataset,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same question as I try to implement `Examples-proportional mixing` from the T5 paper. I didn't find support from [hugging face](https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/issues/217).

My current solution is to modify the `trainer.train_dataset` in the `on_epoch_begin` callback.

Here's an implementation. I'm using this in my [own project](https://github.com/StefanHeng/Symbolic-Music-Generation). Seems to work.

First, implement your per-epoch change in your Dataset, in my case, it's the `sample` function for Examples-Proportional Mixing.

```py
class ProportionMixingDataset:
    """
    Examples-proportional mixing from T5
    TODO: failed to find a pytorch working implementation

    Equivalent to, for the larger datasets, a new subset is taken at each epoch,
        then sample in the joined subset once
    """

    def __init__(self, dataset_list: List[Dataset] = None, k: int = None):
        """
        :param dataset_list: Ordered list of datasets
        :param k: Artificial limit
        """
        self.dsets = dataset_list
        assert k is not None
        self.k = k

        self.dset_szs = [min(len(d), k) for d in self.dsets]
        self.sz = sum(self.dset_szs)

        self._sampled_idxs: List[Optional[torch.Tensor]] = [None] * len(self.dsets)
        self.sample()

    def sample(self):
        """
        Sub-sample datasets larger than k

        Intended to call in each epoch
        """
        for i, dset in enumerate(self.dsets):
            sz = len(dset)
            if sz > self.k:
                self._sampled_idxs[i] = torch.randperm(sz)[:self.k]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.sz

    def _idx2dset_idx(self, idx: int) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        """
        Convert a global index to a dataset index
        """
        for i, sz in enumerate(self.dset_szs):
            if idx < sz:
                return i, idx
            idx -= sz
        raise ValueError('Should not happen')

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if not isinstance(idx, int):
            raise ValueError('Batched indexing not supported')
        idx_dset, idx = self._idx2dset_idx(idx)
        dset = self.dsets[idx_dset]
        if self._sampled_idxs[idx_dset] is not None:  # A sub-sample index
            idx = self._sampled_idxs[idx_dset][idx].item()
        return dset[idx]
```

Then pass that dataset to `Trainer`.

Now comes the magic part:

```py
class ProportionalMixCallback(TrainerCallback):
    """
    Trigger re-computing subset for dataset Examples-proportional mixing, see `dataset::ProportionMixingDataset`

    A hack that modifies the train dataset, pointed by Trainer's dataloader
    """
    def __init__(self, trainer: Trainer):
        self.trainer = trainer

    def on_epoch_begin(self, args: TrainingArguments, state, control, **kwargs):
        self.trainer.train_dataset.sample()
```

Pass this to your trainer as a callback.

This triggers the `sample` call which modifies the dataset at the times we need it.

This works becasue `train_dataLoader` in trainer still points to the same train dataset object.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just a note that huggingface by default passes the `train_dataloader` in the `kwargs`, so you can avoid passing `trainer` to `__init__()`